# System.InvalidOperationException: ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is open

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

Hi So I have an error appearing in logs, and some functionality is sometimes broken, it's intermittent though.

The full stack trace looks lie this:

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is open. at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.GetOpenConnection(String method) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ValidateConnectionForExecute(String method, SqlCommand command) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ValidateCommand(String method, Boolean async) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method) at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed) at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext) at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior) at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute[TResultType](ObjectContext context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues) at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess) at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__5() at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation) at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption) at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection`1.Load(List`1 collection, MergeOption mergeOption) at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.DeferredLoad() at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.LazyLoadBehavior.LoadProperty[TItem](TItem propertyValue, String relationshipName, String targetRoleName, Boolean mustBeNull, Object wrapperObject) at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.LazyLoadBehavior.<>c__DisplayClass7`2.<GetInterceptorDelegate>b__1(TProxy proxy, TItem item) at System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Product_49EFA7CB993633FA6F92A211A42F2C206E79CC0974B0D20D2E9E66248C8DC082.get_ProductSpecificationAttributes() at Nop.Plugin.Widgets.Enhancements.Controllers.ProductController.ProductDetail_SizesDropDownStockLevelsOverall(Int32 productId, String productColor) at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__3d() at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f() at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f() at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f() at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f() at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f() at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f() at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f() at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f() at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<>c__DisplayClass2b.b__1c() at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

I seen some solutions about multiple active result sets in the connection string, but apparently thats a workaround and not a solutiuon.

The stack trace takes me to this section of code, though I can't quite work out what it is.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ProductDetail_SizesDropDown(int productId, string productColor)
    {
        string dropdownOptions = "";
        string dropdownOptionsSizes = "";
        var allSizes = new List<Tuple<string, int>>();
        var product = _productService.GetProductById(productId);
        if (product == null)
        {
            return Json(new
            {
                success = false
            });
        }
        var parentProductId = (product.ParentGroupedProductId > 0) ? product.ParentGroupedProductId : productId;

        var childProducts = _cacheManager.Get("CHILD_PRODUCTS_" + parentProductId, () => _productService.GetAssociatedProducts(parentProductId));

        if (childProducts.Count() == 0)
        {
            return Json(new
            {
                success = false
            });
        }

        foreach (var childProduct in childProducts)
        {
            var sizeSpec =
                childProduct.ProductSpecificationAttributes.FirstOrDefault(
                    x => x.SpecificationAttributeOption != null && x.SpecificationAttributeOption.SpecificationAttribute != null && x.SpecificationAttributeOption.SpecificationAttribute.Name == "Size");
            if (sizeSpec != null)
            {
                var size = this.GetSpecValue(sizeSpec);
                allSizes.Add(new Tuple<string, int>(size, sizeSpec.SpecificationAttributeOption.DisplayOrder));
            }
        }

        allSizes = allSizes.Distinct().OrderBy(x => x.Item2).ToList();

        var countSizes = 0;
        foreach (var sizeTuple in allSizes)
        {
            var size = sizeTuple.Item1;
            var disabled = "";
            var selected = "";

            var sizeProduct = _cacheManager.Get("SIZE_PRODUCT_" + parentProductId + "_" + sizeTuple.Item1 + "_" + productColor, 60, () =>
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(productColor))
                {
                    return _productService.GetAssociatedProducts(parentProductId).FirstOrDefault(x =>
                        x.ProductSpecificationAttributes.Any(psa =>
                            psa.SpecificationAttributeOption != null && psa.SpecificationAttributeOption.SpecificationAttribute != null && psa.SpecificationAttributeOption.Name == sizeTuple.Item1 &&
                            psa.SpecificationAttributeOption.SpecificationAttribute.Name == "Size") &&
                        x.ProductSpecificationAttributes.Any(psa =>
                            psa.SpecificationAttributeOption != null && psa.SpecificationAttributeOption.SpecificationAttribute != null && psa.SpecificationAttributeOption.Name == productColor &&
                            psa.SpecificationAttributeOption.SpecificationAttribute.Name == "Colour"));
                }
                else
                {
                    return _productService.GetAssociatedProducts(parentProductId).FirstOrDefault(x =>
                        x.ProductSpecificationAttributes.Any(psa =>
                            psa.SpecificationAttributeOption != null && psa.SpecificationAttributeOption.SpecificationAttribute != null && psa.SpecificationAttributeOption.Name == sizeTuple.Item1 &&
                            psa.SpecificationAttributeOption.SpecificationAttribute.Name == "Size"));
                }
            });

            // No size child exists for this product so we don't add to the dropdown
            if (sizeProduct == null)
                continue;

            var sizeLabel = size;
            if (sizeProduct != null)
            {
                var stockLabel = RefreshProductStockLabel(sizeProduct.Id, false);

                if (stockLabel.ToLower().Contains("out of stock"))
                {
                    stockLabel = "Out of stock";
                }

                if (stockLabel.ToLower() == "out of stock" || stockLabel.ToLower() == "low stock")
                {
                    sizeLabel += " <strong class=\"" + stockLabel.ToLower().Replace(" ", "-") + "\">" + stockLabel + "</strong>";
                }

                if (stockLabel.ToLower() == "out of stock" && !sizeProduct.PreorderAvailableNew)
                {
                    disabled = " disabled='disabled'";
                    selected = "";
                }
            }

            dropdownOptionsSizes += String.Format("<option value='{0}'{2}{3} data-text='{1}'>{0}</option>",
                HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(size.Replace("\"", "")), HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(sizeLabel), disabled, selected);

            countSizes++;
        }
        dropdownOptions = "<option value=''>Choose from " + countSizes + " sizes</option>" + dropdownOptionsSizes;


        return Json(new
        {
            success = true,
            dropdownOptions
        });
    }
```

I think I may need to use to list, when I grab the child products though I'm not sure.

```
var childProducts = _cacheManager.Get("CHILD_PRODUCTS_" + parentProductId, () => _productService.GetAssociatedProducts(parentProductId));
```

Any guidance would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the key bit:

```
    System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.DeferredLoad() 
at  System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.LazyLoadBehavior.LoadProperty[TItem]
```

Your service is returning Entities with Lazy Loading enabled. Lazy Loading entities have a reference to the DbContext that loaded them, and so can't be accessed by multiple threads, or accessed after the DbContext instance is Disposed.  So if you're returning the objects from a controller method for serialization, or caching them for use by other requests, Lazy Loading must be disabled.

You need to [turn off lazy loading for entities that will get serialized or cached](http://Turn%20lazy%20loading%20off%20for%20serialization).

Comment: Hi David, yep was a threading issue, there were two functions running which were using the same entities.
I was not aware this can happen, but now I do :)
Thanks